# presence of className preventing onClick handler being called

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a simple React component:

```
class FilterCheckBox extends React.Component {

  clickCheckBox(e) {
    console.log('clicked on checkbox');
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <div>
        <a className="filter-checkbox" onClick={this.clickCheckBox.bind(this)}>
          <span>{this.props.area.key}</span>
          <span>{this.props.area.doc_count}</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

With the className specified as above, the onClick handler is never called. However if I remove the className declaration, the onClick works fine.

The styles added by the class are:

```
.filter-checkbox,
.filter-checkbox:link,
.filter-checkbox:visited,
.filter-checkbox:focus {
  -moz-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
  color: #546e7a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: normal normal 700 0.875em/1.2em "Oxygen", sans-serif;
  /*14px*/
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* line 330, ../scss/partials/_reusables.scss */
.filter-checkbox:before,
.filter-checkbox:link:before,
.filter-checkbox:visited:before,
.filter-checkbox:focus:before {
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  content: '';
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cfd8dc;
  color: #007cba;
  clear: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 15px;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: -3px 10px 0 0;
}
/* line 347, ../scss/partials/_reusables.scss */
.filter-checkbox:after,
.filter-checkbox:link:after,
.filter-checkbox:visited:after,
.filter-checkbox:focus:after {
  display: none;
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #ffffff;
  font: normal normal 400 11px/11px FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}
/* line 356, ../scss/partials/_reusables.scss */
.filter-checkbox:hover,
.filter-checkbox:link:hover,
.filter-checkbox:visited:hover,
.filter-checkbox:focus:hover {
  color: #50d583;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* line 361, ../scss/partials/_reusables.scss */
.filter-checkbox.active:before,
.filter-checkbox:link.active:before,
.filter-checkbox:visited.active:before,
.filter-checkbox:focus.active:before {
  border: 1px solid #50d583;
  background: #50d583;
}
/* line 365, ../scss/partials/_reusables.scss */
.filter-checkbox.active:after,
.filter-checkbox:link.active:after,
.filter-checkbox:visited.active:after,
.filter-checkbox:focus.active:after {
  display: block;
}
```

I can't see anything here that would stop the event from being propagated so there must be something I just don't understand properly..?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - umm, pretty sure that's what's already in the <a> tag.

Comment: @cimmanon - replaced sass code with css. I don't really understand how the css could be influencing the event propagation, but then I'm not a css expert

Comment: I've tried commenting out ALL the relevant css rules and the onClick still doesn't get called. Would seem to be React related and doesn't have anything to do with the styles.

Comment: tried putting the className on the containing <div> rather than the <a> tag. Still no joy..

Comment: seems to work just fine for me: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/g14jqLev/)**. it does log `clicked on checkbox` as it should.

Comment: does anyone know why adding className to a component might have this effect? I can't include the whole app here, but it's based on a very cut back version of react-redux-universal-hot-example.

Comment: Is there any parent component enclosing `FilterCheckBox`? Sometimes parent component that triggers re-render causes problem to child event.  I am not sure why removing `className` works but that might be a clue.

Comment: Thanks for your comments/suggestions - I've finally found that there was another script I wasn't aware of that was capturing the click event... grrr

Comment: @PeterWhitfield glad that you have found the problem. Do you mind to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was caused by another script that was capturing the click event using jquery to target that specific class name.

Found through a process of elimination - first eliminating all scripts and restoring until the problem came back. Then inspecting the problem script until I found the offending line.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Chrome devtools allows you to inspect event listeners attached to an element, can consider using that to debug why listeners are not firing in the future.